# Why is this array returning True when put into np.any?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'am trying to recognize an object on the screen by taking a screengrab of it, applying a few basic filters, and then subtracting that image with what it should look like after the filters have been applied. The result of that image subtraction should be an array filled with just [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0] (Which means all the pixels matched when they subtracted, right?), but then when I put that array into an np.any function it always returns True, meaning something in the array is different. But the problem is I've been printing these arrays for debugging and they all show up like this:

```
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
```

What is going on? Shouldn't it return False for this array?

```
#The problem code

difference = cv2.subtract(mainImg,img)
print(difference)
result = np.any(difference)
```

Comment: `[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]` is not showing the entire array. Do `np.where(difference>0)` and show the results here.

Comment: Use `np.nonzero` to find (as the name implies), non zero elements.

Comment: Since you applied filters, the two images generally would not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, it is impossible to know what the correct output should be because when you print it, some elements of the array are being suppressed.

Again suggested in the comments is that you use `np.nonzero` to show only nonzero elements of the array. You can also use `np.where` to find the indices of these elements, which will identify the parts of the images that are different.

However, I am going to suggest that you likely should not be using `np.any` to tell if the images are different. If you are filtering and manipulating the images numerically, this is going to introduce noise that will generally cause them to *always* be different. You may want to use a function like [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to test if the two images are within some given tolerance of each other, a tolerance that you can choose yourself.